# Convert jQuery selector to HTML for a new DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I want to implement a jQuery plugin that converts a selector to HTML. I understand that the mapping between these two syntaxes is many-to-many, but simple selectors would be easy to covert to HTML.

Example:

```
$('div#my-id.my-class').create();
```

might generate:

```
<div id="my-id" class="my-class" />
```

**EDIT**:
The purpose is to create an element if the selector returns an empty set, without having to add redundant code.

```
var jqs = $('div#my-id');
if(jqs.length===0) jqs = jqs.create();
var elementWillAlwaysBeThere = jqs.get(0);
```

Comment: Are you restricted to using CSS selectors for some unfathomable reason? It'd be much more practical to do `var someHTMLElement = $('<div id="my-id" class="my-class">);` and the like.

Comment: The standard `$('<div>', { id: 'my-id', 'class': 'my-class' })` is more semantic and supports setting properties and other methods that wouldn't be possible with a plain selector.

Comment: the purpose is to create the element if the selector returned an empty set without redundant code. `var jqs = $('div#my-id'); if(jqs.length===0) jqs = jqs.create(); var elementWillAlwaysBeThere = jqs.get(0);`

Comment: There's a reason why this is not already impented in any library as far as I know. You should know whether or not you're creating an element or altering an existing element, and the times when you're not sure should be so few that just doing the regular length check on the selector and creating the element like the answers above should be just fine. If you have to create a custom plugin for this, you're doing somthing wrong in my opinion.

Comment: ^ turns out that it IS already implemented as a library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i know this might not be what you are lokking for. the project zen coding is about using a css like syntax to create dom structurs. so i think lokking at there source is going to help you alot, even thou its not pure css selectores.
`div#wrapper>ul#imageSlider>li.image$*3` compiles to:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="imageSlider">
        <li class="image1"></li>
        <li class="image2"></li>
        <li class="image3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

so if you where to use the jQuery port you can do youre example like
`$.zc("div#my-id.my-class")` again resulting in

```
<div id="my-id" class="my-class"></div>
```

happy source reading

Comment: Then thy and check the length of  `foo = $(selector)` call and if its 0 just call `$.zc(foo.selector)`